# How to show QTable CheckBox in QTableView selectively

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtableview

There are two `tableViews`: A and B. `viewA` is linked to `proxyA`. While a `viewB` is linked to `proxyB`. Both proxy share the same `source model`.

From what I've learned `if Qt.CheckStateRole` is specified then the `source model`'s `data()` "assigns" a checkbox to each `modelIndex`.

Since this `checkbox-to-modelIndex assignment` is taking place inside of `sourceModel`'s both views A and B are getting the `checkboxes`.

**Question**: How to isolate `viewA` from getting the `checkboxes`? How to make `viewA` checkbox-less? The goal is to make sure the checkboxes only appear in `viewB`. Is it possible to override some `viewA` property so it doesn't display the checkboxes? May be I could use `viewB` proxy and do some call from proxy 'filterAcceptsRow()`?

The problem apparently is that `sourceModel` is not aware of views. It doesn't care if the indexes are queried for `viewA` or `B`. While with the proxy models I can set `proxyA.setObjectName('proxyA')` and then using its `objectName` do some logic. But how to control the `checkboxes` from inside of Proxy then?....

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_003','Item_000','Item_005','Item_004','Item_001']
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)      
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()

        row=index.row()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.items[row])              

        elif role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            return QVariant(Qt.Checked)
        else:
            return QVariant()


class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        layout=QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        tableModel=Model(self)               

        proxyA=Proxy()
        proxyA.setSourceModel(tableModel)

        proxyB=Proxy()
        proxyB.setSourceModel(tableModel)

        self.ViewA=QTableView(self)
        self.ViewA.setModel(proxyA)

        self.ViewB=QTableView(self) 
        self.ViewB.setModel(proxyB)

        layout.addWidget(self.ViewA)
        layout.addWidget(self.ViewB)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Views just display what model gives them. You need to adjust your models so that viewA's model doesn't give checkbox information. The simpliest solution is to derive from `Proxy` class and reimplement `data()` method. In this method return `QVariant()` if role is `Qt.CheckStateRole` and return base implementation result in other cases. Use this new class for `proxyA` variable.

Comment: Sending back `QVariant()` from source model `data()` method on `if Qt.CheckStateRole` will turn off the checkbox display in a `QTableView`. I've got this by an accident today while working on a code. It is a very nice trick indeed. Thanks for confirming it as well!

Comment: You can earn a point or two if you would edit the source code I've posted in my question and post it as the answer to illustrate this technique. It should not take longer than a few minutes to do! Others probably will appreciate it too.